# DbSet in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following code in Entity Framework:

```
using(var dbc = new TestDbContext())
{
    var data = (from a in dbc.tableList
                select new { a = id }).ToList();
}
```

When I was debugging the code I came across the following piece of code

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
     public TestDbContext()
     { 
     }

     public DbSet<Table> tableList {get;set;}
}
```

I am wondering like without even creating an instance of `DbSet<Table>` like this :

```
public Dbset<Table> tableList = new Dbset<Table>();
```

how am I able to query the table for eg:

in

```
var data = (from a in dbc.tableList
            select new { a = id }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your question is "how DbSet is initialized" or "how EF translates LINQ query  to SQL query"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no magic to this. `TestDbContext` is derived from `DbContext`

`DbContext` makes a call to internal class `DbSetDiscoveryService` which uses Reflection to iterate through `DbSet` properties and initialize them.

The mono version of EF, you can find the code on [Github](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs#L194) that shows the call to `InitializeSets`

Comment: I would say that is the definition of magic. Strange unknown mechanism.

Comment: It's unknown only till you explore the internals :-)

Answer (score 4):

During construction, EF will scan a `DbContext` derived object for any `DbSet` properties and initialize it accordingly via reflection.

From the **Remarks** section on [DbContext documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.aspx).

> `DbContext` is usually used with a derived type that contains `DbSet<TEntity>` properties for the root entities of the model. These sets are automatically initialized when the instance of the derived class is created. This behavior can be modified by applying the `SuppressDbSetInitializationAttribute` attribute to either the entire derived context class, or to individual properties on the class.

---

If you're wondering how it works, you can see the source here:

1. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs
2. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Internal/DbSetDiscoveryService.cs

Comment: for asp.net core 2.2, this happens in class `DbSetInitializer`: `InitializeSets()` method

Answer (score 2):

You TestDbContext inherited from DbContext.
I think, may be inside DbContext constructor via reflection all field like `DbSet<Table>` are initialized.